Can there be unpredictable effects with a cause?
Suppose that we know that B has a cause. Does this imply that there must be a way to predict when B happens in principle through scientific laws or some other mechanism? Or no?
When I think about it, it seems yes. If A causes B, then knowing that A occurs would help us know if B occurs. So if we can predict A, then we can predict B. So it seems as if this depends if A is also predictable?
But what if A is the initial point of the universe? A wouldn’t have a cause. But let’s say we figure out some effect of A called B. Can we now predict B in principle?
Note that “by principle” I mean what is actually true as a matter of reality, not what can actually be done from a practical standpoint. For example, some things are theoretically possible but not practically possible.

Yes, typically all causes we deal with have unpredictable effects. There is a difference between a cause and a sufficient cause, only the latter determines the effect completely. A rock thrown into a window is not a sufficient cause of its shattering, a gust of wind could have blown it off course. An atom emitting a photon after getting hit by one has a cause, it is its excitation as the result of the hit, but the timing is random, only the probability that it happens in some time interval can be predicted even 'in principle'.

By cause I did mean sufficient cause actually as per your characterization @Conifold I had thought that’s what cause in common parlance means anyways. But even if it didn’t, that’s what I mean by it. So if an effect has a sufficient cause, does this imply predictability in principle of that effect? Does this also apply if the cause for the effect does not have a further cause itself (such as the initial conditions of the universe)?

Then the question is vacuous: if an effect is determined by its cause is it determined by its cause?

Also I don’t get the rock example. A rock being thrown into a window is a cause for its shattering. I think what you meant to say is that throwing a rock into a window does not imply that it shatters? But if a rock impacts a window and it shatters, then the rock is the cause of the shattering. But anyways, I don’t wanna digress too much. This isn’t really relevant to the question, just got confused by your example

@Conifold That’s what I was wondering as well. Is it vacuous or not? Hm. If an effect has a cause, the cause determines that effect. But one would also have to predict the cause to predict the effect, no? Now what if this cause is the initial conditions of the universe? For example, suppose that the universe 3 seconds after the Big Bang was caused by the initial conditions of the universe and something else but we don’t know what (maybe a law). How does this imply by itself that we can predict what happens at 3 seconds given the initial conditions of the universe?

The more I think about it the more it does seem vacuous. I need to think about this more.

The rock is not the sufficient cause of the shattering whether it happens or not, that there is no wind is part of it too, if it is to be sufficient. Prediction 'in principle' and prediction by us are two different things. If one knows a sufficient cause, which will be the state of the entire universe under classical mechanics, at least, then they can predict everything, 'in principle'. One would have to be no less than Laplace's demon to do that. We, on the other hand, cannot predict even the microstate of a gas with sufficiently many particles even if we knew its initial state.

It feels like you are trying to expand a basic concept of rationale from the (metaphorical) microscopic scale to the (literal) cosmic scale. "If we know A causes B and B occurs then A must have occurred" is fine for a hypothetical 2-factor system (where you only have A and the possibility of B) but the logic doesn't hold up to any real scrutiny. What if B can be caused by any number of other possible factors, or combinations there of? How do you know IF you know all of the factors that can cause B? -- Suffice to say in a sufficiently complex system predictability becomes a bit 'quantum'.

@Conifold So the Laplace demon stuff I fully understand. I’m still confused by “The rock is not the sufficient cause of the shattering whether it happens or not, that there is no wind is part of it too, if it is to be sufficient.” Isn’t this like saying me stabbing someone isn’t a sufficient cause for someone feeling pain since one also needs the condition that that someone has working nerves? There are an infinite number of unsaid conditions that have to be true when we talk about causes and effects.

It seems after thinking about it that almost nothing we ever talk about qualifies as a sufficient reason by your definition. That may be true but then I question the usefulness of a term that no one alludes to when they think about a reason/cause

This is where you can have cause of common parlance or you can have sufficient cause, you cannot have both. Equating colloquial and sufficient causes was your idea, I mentioned that we almost never deal with these  creations of philosophers. In common parlance, we implicitly discard the "infinite number of unsaid conditions" as part of the background, assumed fixed, and single out "the cause", as the game changer. And we do this exactly to make "cause" pragmatically useful, ontology has no part in it. Ontologically, your stabbing is as much part of the sufficient cause as working nerves.

Might I suggest that the title (at least, though possibly the whole question) is moot -- if we say that every effect is the result of a cause! Whether we managed to predict it or not. -- This whole discussion is trending more towards Physical solutions than Philosophical ones. Do you want a scientific answer or the metaphysical one?

Events can be unpredictable, but have causes. The best example is radioactive decay, as for example in a chunk of uranium 235. This occurs because the nucleus is energetically metastable and can move towards greater stability by splitting in two.
The splitting process itself requires the chance alignment of the protons and neutrons in the nucleus to produce a configuration which is highly unstable to any sort of further perturbation i.e., it has zero fission activation energy and then spontaneously blows up.
A convenient lump of U-235 would contain roughly ten followed by twenty-three zeros of individual atoms but the laws of physics prevent us from predicting the decay of any particular atom in that chunk. All we can say is how much time it takes on average for half of the atoms in the chunk to decay, and we call that result the half-life of U-235.
Note that the half-life of a single atom is a meaningless concept. It might decay one microsecond from now or a million years from now, and there's no way to know in advance.

It seems that you’re confusing decay with decay time. You can predict if an atom will decay, but not predict the time at which it will decay. So the time at which it decays is an unpredictable event. You said that this unpredictable event has a cause. What’s the cause for an atom decaying at a particular time? If there is none, then it doesn’t seem like you gave an example of an unpredictable event that has a cause

Will rewrite. -NN


It is easy to talk about the origin of the universe or “the initial
point of the universe”. But our concepts are not strong enough to
deal with such terms. Using those term fools us around in an unending
loop of problematic concepts and questions like “the cause of the
universe”, “what was before the universe?”, “does the universe had a
creator”?, “if yes, which properties has the creator?”…

Of course it would be erroneous to conclude from this aporia that the
universe exists since eternity. Doing alike provides similar unending
questions.

It was Kant, who in his Critique of Pure Reason, B 452ff, concluded,
that our concepts about the universe as a whole cannot apply to the world of experience. They only produce
antinomies. See Kant's antinomies.
I
think Kant was right, and we should take his warning seriously.



It feels like your question is attempting to compare the following 2 statements as if they're equal:

(A) Someone hits me in the face --leads to--> (B) My face hurts
(A) A Butterfly flaps it wings --leads to--> (B) A hurricane on the other side of the world

Now you could argue that the 'hit' doesn't infact cause the pain you feel so much as trigger the series of events: signals getting transmitted from skin receptors through nerve endings, up through your nervous system and in to your brain, where a series of receptors and neuro-chemical transmitters react to the stimulus, the result of which gives you the perceived sensation of 'pain'.
However the limits of our closed system for this experience are sufficiently well known, tested and proven (though not without exceptions and/or anomalies) for our initial statement to be considered a rational (if simplified) explanation.
With the second statement however, when we ask:

Was the Butterfly THE singular or explicit causal factor that triggered the hurricane on the other side of the world? - Extremely doubtful!
Could it (by some unimaginably large chain soup of causal events) have contributed to the hurricane happening? - Entirely possible.

What that thought experiment tries to teach us is that the causal complexity of the world we live in/on (and it's greater universe/reality) is far too great to comprehend.
Humans tend to think linearly (as it's how we perceive 'time') but our reality isn't causally a chain of dominoes falling down but rather a bag full of dominoes being shaken about vigorously - Everything is constantly interacting with everything else, so a singular event is being 'caused' from all directions at once.

However this is Philosophy not Physics so it becomes reasonable to say you could predict that, given a long enough period of time, everything that can happen will happen!
(for a given starting state in a sufficiently complex system filled with a natural source of chaotic entropy)
-- probably!

Two observations you might want to consider...
Causes and effects are chained. If an alarm goes off in a nuclear power plant, you can then predict that staff at the plant will react to it; however, you might not have been able to predict the factor that triggered the alarm in the first place, so the reaction of the staff only becomes predictable beyond some point along the chain from the root cause.
You will often encounter the observation that things would be predictable 'in principle' if all of the relevant facts were known in sufficient detail, as you could then calculate the effects of all the interactions between the various moving parts. That is an unjustified claim. I remember a very frustrating experience when I was studying for a PhD and writing programs to simulate interactions in quantum mechanics. Literally for weeks I struggled to find what was causing my computer program to produce unrealistic results. Eventually I proved that there was no bug as such- it was simply that the calculations were so iterative that they magnified the tiny rounding errors that resulted from the finite precision with which the computer modelled real numbers. Those rounding errors are also present in reality. You cannot calculate the position of an electron, say, to an arbitrary degree of precision, because an electron does not have a position to an arbitrary degree of precision. You might develop a computer that can model real numbers to a thousand decimal places, but there is no evidence that quantities in nature, such as masses, times, positions, are so specific. Inevitably, therefore, in complicated systems involving countless interactions, the effects of the natural rounding errors will make it impossible to model the future behaviour of the system with complete accuracy, simply because of inherent inaccuracies in nature itself.

Thoughtful answer. But Is it an inaccuracy in nature or an inherent inaccuracy in modeling?

I think it is in nature. If you have formulae that include quantities such as the sine of an angle and so on, there is an unconscious assumption that the values encountered in nature can be expressed as real numbers, ie to an infinite number of decimal places. There's no evidence at all that anything in nature is exact in that way. Nature is inherently fuzzy.

But if mathematics is merely an abstract way of representing things, then of course it can’t be precise, and that would seem to still indicate the fuzzy nature of modeling and not reality. What would it even mean for reality to be fuzzy? Fuzziness and preciseness of a position for example depends upon a reference frame but reference frames depend upon how you model things

I think we are talking at cross purposes. For reality to be fuzzy, in this context, simply means that there are not clear dividing lines between, say, the position of one atom and the next, that an electron does not have an exact position, that an event such as the mission of a photon does not happen at an exact instant. All those things have an inherent uncertainty about them, however minuscule.

"you can then predict that staff at the plant will react to it" a sound hypothesis, but also an assumption. Jeff might have his headphones in blasting some deth metal whilst reading the latest copy of his favourite graphic novel, he might be a bad employee but at least he's unpredictable. -- Predictions are by their very nature not absolute guarantees, they're our "best guess" given the information available. -- Again though, this is the Philosophy stack, not the Physics stack!

@Bucky absolutely- you are very right to point out that there is often an element of uncertainty.

Even "non fuzzy" macroscopic world has this. I had similar issues doing numerical computation modeling of a simple macroscopic chaotic system. Sensitive dependence on initial conditions doesn't mess around.

Even granting a deterministic world, the inescapable fact of measurement error (instruments being incapable of infinite precision, not mistakes or ignorance) means that there are events whose causes can only be expressed stochasitcally and initial conditions whose outcomes can only be expressed stochastically.
Consider the following toy system:
Assume strict determinism. Neglect all quantum effects.
To the limit of our measurements, a perfectly inert perfect conic homogenous solid is perfectly balanced on its tip a perfectly inert perfect horizontal plain in a perfect vacuum.
We know with absolute certainty that the cone will tip over, but we cannot predict the direction it will tip over. And after it tips over and we know where, we can only make guesses about the reason for that direction. A tiny vibration? A slight imperfection in the solid, the vacuum, the configuration, or the surface?

All effects have a cause. All effects are unpredictable with absolute accuracy. There are no sufficient causes in reality.
Macro scale effects can be predicted with sufficient accuracy for most practical purposes.
Quantum scale effects can only be predicted statistically by calculating the probability distribution of the effect.
